# What are the ethical responsibilities of a Stack Exchange Member

Tags: ethics

I have seen several posts lately where the poster appears to be severely depressed with some discussing suicide as a solution. What are the ethical responsibilities for a stack exchange member reading these types of posts (apart from suggesting counseling or medical attention)? Are these posts common during the holiday season?

If these questions are not appropriate I will delete this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

besides recommending treatment by a behavioral health specialist, your ethical responsibility is to do no harm. This means no disparaging or critical commentary.

Comment: Often those depressive questions are combined with puzzling bits of folk philosophy like "what if I have to be reincarnated as myself eternally ?". I think dismissing this kind of fear without agressivity is important ("what reason do you have to think it is the case?") but also worry that it could be interpreted as disparaging or critical.

Comment: Thanks Niels. It's difficult because a cry for help is being disguised as a legitimate philosophical question. Do no harm is a good motto for these types of posts.